# problem with xampp and PHP

Tags: php, xampp

I have one PC and one notebook, I have been working on a project with php for a long time and it is working perfectly in the notebook but today I transported it to the PC and when I started it, it showed a lot of errors and notices!

**Notice:** Undefined variable: .......

**error:** Strict Standards: Non-static method ....... should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in .....

the XAMPP version that I use in the PC is: 1.7.4 and the PHP version is 5.3.5
the XAMPP version that I use in the notebook is: 1.7.3 and the PHP version is 5.3.1

any suggestions? Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the difference in the PHP settings that does this.

The error level for your PC is probably `E_ALL`, whereas error level for your laptop is probably `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`.

Comment: can you please provide me more help on how to change this setting? if possible...

Comment: change this in the php.ini file found in the XAMPP binary folder. look for error_reporting

Comment: what do you think? should I fix all of those problems or not? because I havent tried this in a real hosting server. do you know what are the default settings for PHP in most of web hosting providers?

Comment: Error messages are there to help you write good code, not to annoy you :)

Comment: @Alvaro indeed. I totally agree with him. I'll usually set to show all errors and warnings, and fix my code until all errors and warnings till none before continue developing.